# Why does the 'Deployed' state of the 'Analytics Workflow' modify my campaign item in Sitecore 8.1?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have an item under **/system/Marketing Control Panel/Campaigns** of type **/templates/System/Analytics/Campaign**, and it's in the **/Workflows/Analytics Workflow** workflow.

When the item's workflow state is '*draft*', I can edit/save fields and they retain the values that I saved.  When the item is given the '*Deployed*' workflow state, the value of the 'Display Name' field always gets set to the value of the 'Title' field.  Both when the item enters the state, and every time I edit/save the item.

This is only happening in 8.1 (not 8.0 or below), and happens if I set the state directly to '*Deployed*', or if I move the stated to '*Deployed*' through the workflow.

Sorry this gif is jacked up, but you can see when I change from draft to deployed, the name in the content tree changes, as well as the 'Display name' field.  When I try to change it in the 'deployed' state, it changes it back immediately.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with screen shots?

Comment: I'm not a seeing a "Display Value" field in either version of 8.1, is it a custom field? Anything in the logs?

Comment: @DerekHunziker oops, 'Display Name'

Comment: @AhmedOkour added screen.  I'll try with a new 8.1 out of the box

Comment: @MStodd I just tested this on fresh 8.1 instance and couldn't reproduce this, Do you any custom Action under "Deployed" state?

Comment: @AhmedOkour nope, looks normal.  Might just live with this anomaly, but would be nice to know why

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a bug, however, I would confirm with Sitecore support to be 100% certain.

When you save an item, Sitecore will trigger the `OnItemSaved` event handler within `Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.ItemEventHandler` as shown below:

[image: event handler]

This handler checks to see if the item is in the final workflow state (which it is), and if so, deploys the definition and attempts to update the item's referring items with certain changes:

[image: Item changes]

However, instead of updating referring items, it appears to be re-playing changes against the current item, not the referring items. There is also a place where the title is updated specifically for campaigns.

[image]

In short, I'm not sure why it's occurring and you should probably check with support on this one.

Comment: sitecore support was able to reproduce it, so they're doing some more research.  Thanks for the response!